# Google IoT Core registry with additional telemetry topic and wildcard in subfolder?

Tags: google-cloud-iot

I want to add telemetry topics to a registry and distribute telemetry streams to different pubsub topics. Since our MQTT topics on the devices use more than one subfolder, the registry's subfolder string does not match **exactly** to the pubsub topic.

For example, our device sends telemetry to the topic:
*/devices/devId/events/pubsubTopicId/additionalInfo/evenMoreInfo*

I'd wish the resulting pubsub messages to be placed in the topic */projects/projectId/topics/pubsubTopicId* and to have the *pubsub subfolder* property like */additionalInfo/evenMoreInfo*.

Instead currently, all messages are published in the registry's default pubsub topic.

So this question is more of a feature request to the google team to enable **wildcards** in the *subfolderMatches* property of registry's *EventNotificationConfig*. Than a positive match could be evaluted if the first subfolder after */devices/devId/events* would match.

Thx for your answer!

Answer (score 3):

I hear the feature request, and I can bring that to our engineering team.

As a possible solution for now...what if you set up something where the telemetry always goes to the /devices/devId/events/pubsubTopicId/ folder. And then inside the telemetry payload, you had subfolders where you wanted things going in addition to that, and you ran a cloud function, or a dataflow pipeline to parse the payload, and send the telemetry to the appropriate bucket?

Comment: Thank you for communicating that to the engineers. We'll probably only use the registry's default telemetry topic for now.

Comment: Sounds good, if you have more questions, feel free to reach out on Twitter (easier to get ahold of me than SO generally).